# Does one open a browser “on” a URL?

Tags: phrases, prepositional-phrases

Can I say:

> It opens the browser on the URL **[X]**

meaning that something is opening the browser with the URL **[X]** already typed in and loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preposition *on* may be acceptable in that context, but is less suitable than *with*, *using*, or *at*.  You might also reword the sentence, for more-proper semantics:

> It opens the browser to display the page at URL ...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may. *With* or *at* are more common, but a Google search for "browser on url" shows plenty of hits with this usage, for example: [How to open a browser on a given URL](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/howto_openbrowserurl.htm)

Comment: _With_ is certainly not more common in this context—it is quite nonsensical, I would say. “Clicking the _Learn more_ button will open your browser with the URL www.xyz.com/learnmore/”, for instance, is very clearly not right. I would only use _with_ when the verbal and prepositional objects are switched: you open a URL _with_ your browser, but you open your browser _on/to/at_ a URL.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, you are right that "with" is less common, but it's not nonsensical. Again, just Google search for the exact phrase "open your browser with the URL" and you will see many examples. I'm not saying the number of hits is significant, but the context of most hits indicates that the usage is as above and the writer is generally someone who should know better.

Answer (score 2):

You may **open url in/with a browser**.

Order of the action: usually you open a browser, then the browser opens url.

In case you have some "shorcuts" on your "desktop" you may open "the browser with the url" by clicking it. That means, the browser will be opened with the url adress embedded in shortcut.

You may "open url in a browser" - you type the url to the browser address bar.

Personally, I have never heard of **open browser on url**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it opens the browser to the url.

The url represents a location(on a server somewhere) that the browser moves to. The browser does not contain/possess the url so you can't open a browser with a url.

It's like:
"Drive your car with your house." vs "Drive your car to/at your house."

Comment: Why might *to* be better than *at* or *with*?

Comment: While I can follow your reasoning, "to" doesn't seem common here. In fact, I've never heard "open X to Y" before. You might, however, say "*point* the browser to <URL>".